# A Little help for displaying absolute button on top of the image

Tags: html, css

I wanna show an absolute button on top of my first google images. Basically, this button is suppose to be in the first `div` container's and top of the first image. I repeat some thing to see whether it is working properly or not. However, the second absolute button does not appear, I guess it is under the first absolute button. How to fix it to show each absolute buttons in the corresponding `div` container's first google image(white one).

I have done this (http://jsbin.com/kenute/1/edit), but it does not show properly. Here I also use borders to see the problem caused by `div` tags, but still some problems i do not understand why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything positioned absolutely must be contained within an element that has relative positioning